# angularjs Watching rootscope changes

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to bind to rootscope so that I can set presence on a different server when the user logins.
Here's my module.

```
angular.module('presence', 
  [
  ]
)

.run(function ($rootScope) {
  $rootScope.$watch($rootScope.currentUser, function () {
    console.log('change currentUser')
    console.log($rootScope.currentUser)
    presence.setGlobal({
      u: $rootScope.currentUser,
      s: 'on'
    })
  })
})
```

There's no controller because it's just about the global presence of the user and has nothing to do with the DOM.

This is not working, the watch runs once but never again on subsequent changes. Thanks for your help.

Edit: Login code looks like this:

```
  $scope.login = function() {
    $http.post('http://localhost:3000/login', $scope.user).success(function(res, status) {
      if (res && res._id) {
        $rootScope.currentUser = res
      }
    }).error(function(res, status) {
      $scope.error = res.err
    });
  };
```

This code updates fine in the DOM. It shows the username in the html for example:

```
a.user(ui-if="currentUser", ng-href="/user/{{currentUser._id}}") {{currentUser.username}}
```

Comment: RootScope is only the root scope for this instance of the application you'll want to use a service/factory instead and somehow persist the presence change somewhere.

Comment: @xmltechgeek can you give an example of how to do it properly? That sounds like what I need to learn thanks

Comment: try setting the `$rootScope.currentUser` to a dummy value on error as well to check if that is the cause.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

The syntax was `$rootScope.$watch('currentUser')` not `$rootScope.$watch($rootScope.currentUser)`

Comment: Hi, where do you write this statement?

Comment: Anywhere you have a $rootScope injected.

Answer (score 1):

Something needs to change `$rootScope.currentUser` for you to be able to notice any changes in it. You have shared the code for that.

Also changes to `$rootScope.currentUser` need to take place inside the angularJS loop (http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/concepts). If it is done externally you can call $digest (http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootScope.Scope#$digest)