# How to watch $rootScope on entire angular JS application

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular 1.5.6 and my application is composed of several modules, each module has his own view and controller. My question is how can I watch $rootScope on each of those controllers. I need to watch $rootScope on all controllers because I have a global variable on $rootScope.account and when user refresh the page $rootScope.account is cleared and all my application crash. I would like to watch $rootScope.account on all my modules, so when a user refresh I can handle the refresh and redirect to login page. I thought maybe of a service that I would inject on all each of my modules?

Comment: Yes you could/should use a factory. You could also store the user account in Local Storage to avoid loosing it after a refresh.

Comment: Try some google chrome extension something like `ng-inpector` through which will be quite handful. Here is the URL - https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ng-inspector-for-angularj/aadgmnobpdmgmigaicncghmmoeflnamj

Comment: Possible duplicate of [angularjs Watching rootscope changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16888166/angularjs-watching-rootscope-changes)

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in two simple ways.

First: include `$rootScope` into your controller:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', [
    '$rootScope',
    '$scope',
    function($rootScope, $scope) {
        $rootScope.$watch('myvar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            doSomething();
        }

        //...
    }
]);
```

Second. If you don't have variables with same names in the other scopes then you can avoid using `$rootScope` and use just `$scope`. This will work because every `$scope` is inherited from `$rootScope`.

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', [
    '$scope',
    function($scope) {
        $scope.$watch('myvar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
            doSomething();
        }

        //...
    }
]);
```

Comment: Hi, thanx. The first solution would fix my issue I think, but like this I have to add function($rootScope, $scope)... on every module which would make a lot of code duplication, isn't there a way to put the $rootScope.$watch in a service and simply add inject this service in all my modules?

Comment: just put this code in `app.run(['$rootScope', function($rootScope) { ... }])` if it doesn't depend on controllers.